# Find duplicate values assigned to more than one unique value

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need a query that can compare two columns (DBVersionKey, Desc19).
Logic - If the same Desc19 is used for more than one DBVersionKey, return only those results. Below is the data range (snippet)

DATA SAMPLE

```
DBVersionKey    Desc19
2491            W25170206H
2492            W25170212H
2493            W25170218H
2494            W25170224H
9129            40761KB18X
9191            40761KB18X

EXPECTED RESULT
DBVersionKey    Desc19
9129            40761KB18X
9191            40761KB18X
```

*I have tried GROUP BY, HAVING COUNT and many other theory solutions

I do not want the query to contain any specifics to the data values, due to a potential high volume of affected records

Table name - Table_A

Comment: `mysql` or `sql-server`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT DBVersionKey, Desc19, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Desc19
ORDER BY Desc19) RN
FROM Table_A)

SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
```

I suggest using common table expressions with row number partitions. This creates a count (RN) of each instance of Desc19.

I can't test the query right now, but keep me updated on your results and I can adjust from there.

**EDIT**

If DBVersionKey is not a unique value, I would try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DBVersionKey, Desc19, COUNT(*)
FROM Table_A
Group by DBVersionKey, Desc19
```

Let me know if that works better.

**EDIT 2**

One again, I can't test it. Adding to the first suggested query:

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT DBVersionKey, Desc19, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Desc19 ORDER BY Desc19) RN 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT DBVersionKey, Desc19 FROM Table_A GROUP BY DBVersionKey, Desc19)

SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
```

Comment: alybaba this partially works which is great.

Issue 1 - Need to change the results to prevent showing duplicate DBVersionKey and Desc19 Values (distinct?)
Issue 2 - Counts with 3 either have 3 distinct values or 2 distinct values

Comment: This edit may not work for what you need, run it and let me know!

Comment: ^ relates to the second query, first query does not provide the correct result

Comment: Sorry for the run around, I wish I could test these. See Edit #2.

Comment: The brackets appear to be invalid, as the first DBVersionKey, Desc19 are showing as invalid column names. Last select is expecting AS, ID or Quoted ID

Comment: alybaba - do you have an update on your script please?

Comment: @Elliott_T-SQL are you using MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008

Comment: I have fine tuned your query to work with SQL Server and it is working like a charm, thank you for your support!
I also now understand the logic behind OVER and PARTITION

Comment: @Elliott_T-SQL Great!! Please post your final query, it'll help someone in the future!

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    a.*
from
    Table_A as a
inner join
    (select Desc19
     from Table_A
     group by Desc19
     having count(*) > 1) as b
  on a.Desc19 = b.Desc19 ORDER BY Desc19
```

Comment: Your `GROUP BY` clause will require both the PK and Desc19, I don't believe this will work.

Comment: You mean DBVersionKey, Desc19 ?

Comment: prem89, I have tried that already and I receive the following error:

Column 'ix_spc_planogram.DBVersionKey' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @prem89 yes, DBVersionKey (the Primary Key [PR] of the table)

Comment: @Elliott_T-SQL check this updated query. Does this work?

Answer (score 0):

Correct solution based on EDIT 2 by alybaba726

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT DBVersionKey, Desc19, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Desc19
    ORDER BY Desc19) RN FROM ix_spc_planogram GROUP BY DBVersionKey, Desc19)
SELECT * FROM CTE
    WHERE RN > 1
    ORDER BY RN
```