# Find out columns values associated to more than one columns values in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates

I have a table in oracle with non unique column values. The combinations are also non unique. But association in a particular order has to be unique. I have tried many solutions.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30984050/find-duplicate-values-assigned-to-more-than-one-unique-value)  question is the closest but i need a solution in Oracle SQL. Following is my table

```
--------------------------------------------------
  Teacher           subject             class_id
--------------------------------------------------
    Paul              English              001
    Paul              English              002
    Allen             English              003
    Sia               Maths                134
    John              Computer             913
    Jack              Physics              341
    Arlene            Maths                001
 -------------------------------------------------
```

The query should return only following info

```
English, Maths
```

i.e subjects that are associated to more than one teachers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want subjects that have more than one teacher.  This is a simple aggregation query with a `having` clause:

```
select subject
from t
group by subject
having min(teacher) <> max(teacher);
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you want something like this:

```
select listagg (subject, ', ') within group (order by subject) subjects
from (
    select subject from classes 
    group by subject
    having count(teacher)>1
);

SUBJECTS                                                                       
-------------------------
English, Maths
```

or you can achieve the same result with analytic functions:

```
select listagg (subject, ', ') within group (order by subject) subjects
from (
    select subject,
    count(teacher) over (partition by subject) teachers,
    row_number() over (partition by subject order by class_id) rn 
    from classes
)
where teachers>1 and rn=1
;
```